# How to set the X,Y position of button in frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, layout-manager

How to set the `JButton` position on the `JFrame`?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: By even simple googling you can find out your solution...

Answer (score 4):

> can any one tell me the property to set the button position on the Jframe.

answer is simple --->

use proper [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), in the case that you'll real question edit with description but [SSCCE will be better](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Not a real answer to the question the OP is asking, although it is not asked nicely.

Comment: @Hidde  I don't think an absolute layout is a real answer to any need.  Layouts, using appropriate layout padding, and occasional empty borders, is a much better way to logically layout a GUI that includes white-space.  Try recreating something like the [Nested Layout Example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) (including PLAF change) using an absolute layout (and a `ComponentListener` presumably).

Comment: I agree that you almost never use an Absolute Layout, but I have found use for it once (a small math application with drawings in which buttons were placed. I had to make it unresizable...). Here however, the OP asks for a way to put his button in a NULL Layout, so that's the answer I give him, with further advice.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Absolute Layout (which you must not, horrible resizing capabilities, and a bad habit), you can call on either `.setBounds(int x, int y, int w, int h)`, or `.setLocation(int x, int y)`.

Comment: Whoops, it's `.setLocation (int x, int y)`. Again, you should use a LayoutManager, and not an Absolute Layout unless you really must.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a proper Layout Manager, my favorite is `GridBagLayout` because it's easy to use. You just need to make a `JPanel` and then create `GridBagConstraints` for each component in the `JFrame`. Here's the code (function inside the main class, which is an extension of `JFrame`):

```
public void GridBagLayoutExample() {
    JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()) //create a Panel with a layout
    JButton b = new JButton('Button1');
    GridBagConstraints bconstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    //more code here
}
```

For more information, look in the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).